# Include Guard still inserting Global Variables

Tags: c, global-variables, include-guards

I have 3 `*.c` files (`file1.c`, `file2.c` and `file3.c`) and 1 `*.h` file (`file3.h`) in a project (Visual Studio).

```
/*******************************
file3.h
********************************/
#ifndef FILE3_H
#define FILE3_H
int gintVariable = 400;
#endif
```

```
/*******************************
file1.c
********************************/
#include "file3.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int modifyGlobalVariable(void);
void printGlobalVariable(void);

int main(void)
{
    modifyGlobalVariable();
    printGlobalVariable();
    printf("Global variable: %d\n", gintVariable++);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

```
/*******************************
file2.c
********************************/
#include "file3.h"                      

int modifyGlobalVariable(void) 
{ 
    return gintVariable++; 
}
```

```
/*******************************
file3.c
********************************/
#include "file3.h"
#include <stdio.h>

void printGlobalVariable(void)
{
    printf("Global: %d\n", gintVariable++);
}
```

When I build the solution in VS, it is giving error as `"_gintVariable already defined in file1.obj"`.

I did check in the pre-processor output, the gintVariable is included in all the *.c files even though I have included include guards.

What mistake I am doing?

Comment: Your mistake is assuming include guards protect against multiple definitions. Out of curiosity, what gave you that idea?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: include guards will only include the header if not included. am I correct?

Comment: For the same translation unit, yes. But you're compiling more than one files, correct?

Comment: @OnlyQuestions Include guards work *within one .cpp file.* They prevent multiple inclusion of a header in one file, but not including the same header in different files.

Comment: @Angew: Oh, i got that now. Thanks. Out of curiosity, I want to generate a scenario where, multiple inclusion happens for a single file. Can you give me one example?

Comment: @OnlyQuestions It's pretty common when headers include each other. [Example here](http://pastebin.com/LG9sWrEj).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use '`extern`' while declaring a global variable in header file.
Define it in any one of `*.c` file.
This should fix the issue.

For more on header files, read
[How do I use extern to share variables between source files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/what-are-extern-variables-in-c)

Answer (score 4):

Including guards prevents multiple inclusion (or, more precisely, multiple compilation of the .h file content) in a single translation unit.

It is useful against this problem:

```c
/* glob.h */
#ifndef H_GLOB
#define H_GLOB

struct s { int i; };

#endif
```

```
/* f.h */
#ifndef H_F
#define H_F

#include "glob.h"

struct s f(void);

#endif
```

```
/* g.h */
#ifndef H_G
#define H_G

#include "glob.h"

struct s g(void);

#endif
```

```
/* c.c */
#include "f.h" /* includes "glob.h" */
#include "g.h" /* includes "glob.h" */

void c(void) {
    struct s s1 = f();
    struct s s2 = g();
}
```

The inclusions is like a diamond:

```
    glob.h
   /     \
f.h      g.h
   \     /
     c.c
```